# Submit django model form in mutiple pages

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I have a website where Django forms are used, I want to make my lengthy form into multiple parts. For example part A for personal information, then on clicking next part B of form like Professional information. Is there any way I can split my form into multiple parts?
also I'm using Django templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and thankfully with Django is very easy to do :

```
from django.contrib import admin

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content', 'sites')
        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('registration_required', 'template_name'),
        }),
    )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

Result being :

[image]